# Tagging questions for kicking and flexibility

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

There are a few questions regarding [kicking and flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking-flexibility). However, they are tagged with:

- [flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexibility)
- [kicking](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking)
- [kicking-flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking-flexibility)

I propose to eliminate that last tag and only use the first two as separate tags on each of those questions. This eliminates the redundancy, and I think the two subjects should be separated.

Should the [kicking-flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking-flexibility) be kept or not? What should be done with the current set of questions related to this tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose we abolish, obliterate, destroy, and stamp-out any and all redundancy.

There's really no need to have a tag specifically for [kicking-flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking-flexibility) when the other two describe the subject quite clearly. Tags are great for narrowing down:

"I'm looking for a question about [kicking](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking)... Well, here's questions about high kicks, low kicks, but what I'm interested in is the [flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flexibility) of my kicks..."

Granted, I do have a long-winded interior monologue, but it seems to me I'd be far less likely to jump to "I want questions about [kicking-flexibility](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kicking-flexibility)"

Comment: Agreed, retag & blow away.